# hook to add author name in woocomerce product single page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with a Plugin and going to integrate it with woocomerce. Using my plugin i want to add product author name in product single page .

so i need a hook how to add author name in product single page.
Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this action :

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary','mycustomfuncion',11);
function mycustomfuncion()
{
    global $product;
    $productId = $product->id;  
}
```

In mycustomfuncion() you can get the product Id and by this product id you can fetch author name from your database and just echo the author name.